# Rpy2 - Select Results and Output to CSV File

Tags: output, rpy2

I'm currently doing Cox Proportional Hazards Modeling using Rpy2 - I imagine my question will cover other functions and the results from calling them as well though.

After I run the function, I have a variable which contains the results from the function, in the form of a vector.  I have tried explicitly converting this to a DataFrame (`resultsDataFrame = DataFrame(resultVector)`).  There are no errors returned when doing this.  However, when I do `resultsDataFrame.to_csvfile(filename)` I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#171>", line 1, in <module>
 modelFrame.to_csvfile('/Users/fortylashes/Documents/Matthews_Research/Cox_PH/ResultOutput_Exp1.csv')
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py", line 1031, in to_csvfile
'col.names': col_names, 'qmethod': qmethod, 'append': append})
 RRuntimeError: Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
 cannot coerce class ""coxph"" to a data.frame
```

Furthermore, when I simply do:

```
 for result in resultVector:
        print (result)
```

I get an extremely long list of results- including information on each entry in the dataset used in the model, for each variable (so 9,000 records x 9 variables = 81,000 unneeded results).  The results I really need are at the bottom of this vector and look like this:

```
                    coef       exp(coef)  se(coef)      z       p
   age_age6574   -0.057775     0.944      0.05469   -1.056   2.9e-01
   age_age75plus -0.020795     0.979      0.04891   -0.425   6.7e-01
   sex_female    -0.005304     0.995      0.03961   -0.134   8.9e-01
   stage_late    -0.261609     0.770      0.04527   -5.779   7.5e-09
   access        -0.000494     1.000      0.00069   -0.715   4.7e-01

   Likelihood ratio test=36.6  on 5 df, p=7.31e-07  n= 9752, number of events= 2601
```

*NOTE: There were several more variables for which data was reported in the initial results (the 9,000 x 9 that I was talking about) but weren't actually used in the model.

I was wondering if there was a way to explicitly get this data, put it in one long ordered row, and then output it to a csv file?

::::UPDATE::::

When I call `theModel.names` I get a list of the various measures which can be called by numerical index:

```
 [1] "coefficients"      "var"               "loglik"           
 [4] "score"             "iter"              "linear.predictors"
 [7] "residuals"         "means"             "concordance"      
 [10] "method"            "n"                 "nevent"           
 [13] "terms"             "assign"            "wald.test"        
 [16] "y"                 "formula"           "call"
```

From this I can get the coefficients, which can then be exponentiated.  I have not found, however, the p-value, the z score or the likelihood test ratio, which I will need.

Comment: Anybody have any suggestions?  At all?  I do `theModel.` and then after the `.` have the option to do: `cbind`, `colnames`, `do_slot`, `do_slot_assign`, `iter_column`, `iter_row`, `iteritems`, `list_attrs`, `named`, `names`, `ncol`, `nrow`, `r_repr`, `rbind`, `rclass`, `rid`, `ro`, `rownames`, `rsame`, `rx`, `rx2`, `sample`, `typeof`.  Does any of that help?

Comment: Self-contained examples to reproduce the problem increase the odds to have someone look at it (otherwise guessing what you might be doing, which R package you are using, etc... is an overhead). Otherwise, you might have to call R's base function `summary()` on your model.

Comment: @Igautier thank you for taking the time to respond, as well as for indicating the `summary()` function!  That solves my issue and makes it so I can obtain those stats through indexing!  In the future, I will keep those things in mind.

Comment: @Igautier Also, if you `r_base=importr('base')`, `r_base.summary(theModel)` I will accept your answer.